# Format a raw image to XFS in Proxmox VE

Tags: lxc, xfs, proxmox

I have a system with Proxmox VE 5.1 and a LXC container with Fedora 27.

The container has 2 disk (`raw` format), the rootfs and an additional mount point, both of them are in ext4, I want to format to `xfs` the second mount point.

I've tried to use the typical `mkfs.xfs` but I don't know where the linux block device is stored, It isn't in /dev directory.

The `mount` command shows:

```
/var/lib/vz/images/111/vm-111-disk-1.raw on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/var/lib/vz/images/111/vm-111-disk-2.raw on /var/db_data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

The `df -h` shows:

```
/dev/loop6       20G  1.1G   18G   6% /
/dev/loop7      9.8G   37M  9.3G   1% /var/db_data
```

However the "loopX" devices doesn't exist in container disk.

I've searched in proxmox forums without luck, so I don't know if this is a proxmox limitation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the block device is `/dev/loop7`; It's a *loop device* backed by the file `/var/lib/vz/images/111/vm-111-disk-2.raw`. Per Wikipedia:

> In Unix-like operating systems, a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device), vnd (vnode disk), or
>   lofi (loop file interface) is a pseudo-device that makes a file
>   accessible as a block device.

There's no indication that your disk images contain partitions, so you can either create the filesystem from:

1. Within the container (recommended): `mkfs.xfs /dev/loop7`
2. From the host while the container is NOT *running*: `mkfs.xfs /var/lib/vz/images/111/vm-111-disk-2.raw`

Comment: The first option doesn't work, but the second one is Ok, thx.

Comment: The loop device is only accessible from the host, not within the container.

Answer (score -1):

To access the new drive on the client use "apt install xfs" (if you are using a Debian.)

Comment: The OP has already shown that he can already run `mkfs.xfs` on the host so it's not a case of missing necessary software.

Comment: Incorrect. In general LXC clients can not use host Apps. Only kernel.